# How to load and use word2vec model properly in a web-application via Flask RESTful APIs?

Tags: flask, gensim, word2vec, flask-restful

I built a small code to find analogies using word2vec and it runs fine as stand alone application. Here is the working code

```js
import numpy as np

# Get the interactive Tools for Matplotlib
%matplotlib notebook


from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec
import os
glove_file = os.path.abspath('glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt')
word2vec_glove_file = get_tmpfile("glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt")
glove2word2vec(glove_file, word2vec_glove_file)
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_glove_file)
def analogy(x1, x2, y1):
    result = model.most_similar(positive=[y1, x2], negative=[x1])
    return result[0][0]
analogy('woman', 'queen', 'man')
```

Now, I plan to use flask to create a small web application, so that users can find analogies via the webpage. For this I have a basic question

1. I assume I need to save the model and then load it when I start the server. Please correct me  I am I am wrong.

Here is the code that using Flask, it is working, but can you please suggest if saving model is required here?
2. Any suggestions to improve this code are welcome!

```js
import numpy as np



from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec
import os 

from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def welcome():
    return "Welcome to our Machine Learning REST API!"
@app.route("/analogy", methods=['GET'])
def analogy_route():
    word1 = request.args.get("word1")
    word2 = request.args.get("word2")
    word3 = request.args.get("word3")
    result = model.most_similar(positive=[word3, word2], negative=[word1])
    return str(result[0][0])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    glove_file = os.path.abspath('glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt')
    word2vec_glove_file = get_tmpfile("glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt")
    glove2word2vec(glove_file, word2vec_glove_file)

    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_glove_file)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to be doing the GLoVe-to-word2vec format conversion, into a temporary file, every time you start your service. (It probably takes a noticeable amount of time, and may be filling a temp directory with redundant copies of the same data.)

Instead, perform the conversion only once, into a non-temporary location. Then, ignore the original `glove.6B.100d.txt` file entirely – it's no longer needed. Instead, just ensure the converted file is available to your web service in a stable location.

Very roughly, that means:

1. Run once, anywhere:

```py
glove2word2vec('glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt', `glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt`)
```

(Note that neither the use of `absfile()` for `get_tmpfile()` are strictly necessary – you can supply string paths directly to the `glove2word2vec()` function.)

2. Ensure that the new file `glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt` is available in the working directory of your web service.
3. Have your web service's `__main__` branch just load the already-converted file, avoiding redundant repeated conversion work:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

(The exact path `'glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt'` might be slightly different depending on where you choose to place the full file.)